# confusion with pthread_exit and pthread_cleanup_push on platform windows

Tags: pthreads, mingw-w64

```
// running worker
static void* run_worker(void* arg)
{
    thread_pool_t* pool = (thread_pool_t*)arg;
    worker_t* worker = NULL;
    list_node_t* node = NULL;

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &pool->mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pool->mutex);
        while (pool->worker_size <= 0 && !pool->flag.shutdown)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&pool->cond, &pool->mutex);
        }

        if (pool->flag.shutdown)
        {
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&pool->mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
```

as shown above, I expect that the lock `pool->mutex` would be released automatically cause I push a `pthread_mutex_unlock` at the first. However, it does not do it, does anyone know about that?

Comment: What is the observed manifestation of "it does not do it"? Please clarify that as part of a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Note also, by the way, that a pointer to `pthread_mutex_unlock()` does not have the correct type for the first argument to `pthread_cleanup_push()`.  I don't actually think that's the source of the problem, but technically, it does impart undefined behavior to your program.

Comment: In my test program, there are 3 active threads in the thread pool. I set `pool->flag.shutdown` into `1` firstly and then invoke `pthread_cond_broadcast(&pool->cond)` and then invoke `pthread_join`. I expect that all of the threads would exit with `pthread_exit(NULL)` and release the lock automatically. However, only one thread exit and it did not release the lock automatically.